# Разбор механизмов работы Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не так давно использую язык Python для своих целей. Появился вопрос с реализацией самого языка. Начну с неясностей по порядку:

1. Язык Python, на сколько я понимаю, написал на Си. Но что тогда
   значит Cython ? Это одно и то же ?
2. Если он написан на Си, то как он интерпретируется ? У меня есть
   предположение, что каждая строчка компилируется по отдельности и
   сразу же запускается, так ли это ? Можно где-нибудь почитать
   исходники ?
3. В интернете есть информация о виртуальной машине Python. Что это
   такое ? Я знаю, что у Java такая есть. Но Java не интерпретируемый
   язык. После компиляции, получается байт-код, который потом JRE
   интерпретирует на ходу под конкретную машину. Но тут же нет подобия
   JRE... Или есть ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Строго говоря есть несколько интерпретаторов языка python, написанных на разных языках программирования.

Эталонной реализацией является реализация интерпретатора на си - CPython (си пайтон).

Есть также реализация интерпретатора на Java (Jython), на .Net (IronPython) и даже на самом python (PyPy).

В большинстве случаев достаточно именно эталонной реализации.

Не путайте CPython и Cython - это разные вещи. Первое - это интерпретатор, второе - это дополнение для языка. Так как CPython написан на Си, то в нём можно использовать структуры, специфичные для Си. Этим и занимается проект Cython - в python коде можно объявить структуру из языка Си и потом с ней работать. Нужно, к слову, крайне редко, используется в очень специфичных проектах.

Программы на python переводятся в байт-код при запуске этой программы. При этом создаются файлы с расширением .pyc - скомпилированные. Их можно запустить даже не имея оригинального py файла (и даже перевести обратно в py, если они не были деобфусцированы). Раньше создавались также файлы .pyo - объектные файлы, но начиная с 3.х они больше не создаются. Также в python3 поменялось их местоположение - теперь они помещаются в поддиректорию __pycache__.

Исходники python вы можете найти на [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/) (у них ещё есть read-only зеркало на [github](https://github.com/python/cpython))

**Дополнено:**

Давайте рассмотрим поподробнее python в сравнении с java

У Java есть интерпретатор и виртуальная машина, и у Python есть виртуальная машина, как и интерпретатор. Причина, по которой "виртуальная машина" ближе к Java, а "интерпретатор" ближе к Python, кроется в большой разнице между этими двумя языками: статическая типизация в Java против динамической типизации в Python. Здесь, говоря о типах, я буду иметь в виду структуры данных, хранящихся в памяти и с которыми работает данный язык программирования

Виртуальная машина Java проста - она требует от программиста объявить тип каждой переменной в коде. Это предоставляет достаточное количество информации, чтобы байт-код Java мог интерпретироваться не только виртуальной машиной Java, но и компилироваться в [машинные инструкции](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) (ассемблерный код).

Виртуальная машина Python гораздо сложнее в том плане, что она берёт на себя дополнительные задачи приостановки перед выполнением каждой операции, чтобы определить тип данных каждой переменной или структуры данных, включённых в каждую операцию. Python освобождает программиста от мышления на уровне базовых типов данных * и позволяет сконцентрироваться на более высоком уровне абстракции. Цена за такую свободу - производительность. "Интерпретатор" - это приоритетный термин для Python так как он останавливается для определения тпов данных а также потому что краткий синтаксис динамических языков программирования лучше подходит  для интерактивных интерфейсов. Нет никаких технических преград для того, чтобы сделать интерактивный Java интерфейс, но попытка интерактивно набора статический кода (тут подразумевается какой-нибудь консольный интерпретатор) будет утомительным, поэтому никто так не делает.

В мире Java скрыта вся интерактивность, потому что она запускает программы на языке, который вообще может быть скомпилирован в машинный код и как следствие будет иметь высокую скорость и эффективное расходование ресурсов. Байт-код Java может быть выполнен при помощи виртуальной машины Java с производительностью, сравнимой с программами, скомпилированными в машинный код. Виртуальная машина Java ставит Java в собственную категорию:

**Переносимый интерпретируемый статически типизированный язык**

Наиболее близким к ней является LLVM, но LLVM оперирует на другом уровне:

**переносимый интерпретируемый ассемблерный язык**

Термин "байт-код" используется не только в Java и Python, но не весь байт-код создаётся одинаковым. Байт-код - это лишь общий термин для промежуточных языков, используемый у компиляторах\интерпретаторах. Даже компилятор языка C, например gcc, использует [промежуточный язык(или несколько)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL.html) для своих нужд. Байт-код Java содержит информацию о базовых типах данных, тогда как Python байт-код - нет.В этом смысле виртуальная машина Python (и Bash, Perl, Ruby и пр.) действительно намного медленнее, чем виртуальная машина Java, или даже, если проще, у неё больше работы. Стоит заметить, что информация, содержащаяся в различных байт-кодах отличается по представляемому формату:

- **LLVM:** регистры cpu
- **Java:** базовые типы данных
- **Python:** пользовательские типы данных

Чтобы привести аналогию из реального мира можно представить, что LLVM работает на атомном уровне, Java - на молекулярном, а Python работает с материей. Так как всё может быть разбито на субатомные частицы (машинные операции), то самая сложная работа у виртуальной машины Python.

Интерпретаторы/компиляторы статических языков не имеют такой обузы, как у динамических интерпретаторов/компиляторов. Программисты статических языков вынуждены чем-то жертвовать для производительности. Тем не менее, так же как все недетерминированные функции на самом деле детерминированные, так и все динамически типизированные языки на самом деле статически типизированные. Различия между этими классами языков должны сгладиться со временем и тогда Python можно будет переименовать в [HAL 9000](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_9000)

Виртуальные машины динамических языков, таких как Python, реализуют более идеализированную логическую машину и их не стоит тщательно соотносить с реальным физическим оборудованием. Виртуальная машина Java же наоборот более похожа на классический компилятор C, помимо выполнения машинного кода выполняет встроенные подпрограммы. В Python целое число integer - это объект с кучей атрибутов и методов, связанных с ним. В Java integer - это последовательность бит, обычно 32-х. Это не самое честное сравнение. Целые числа в Python должны сравниваться с классом integer в Java. Тип данных int в Java не может сравниваться ни с чем в Python, потому что Python просто исключает этот уровень абстракции, ровно как и его байт-код**

Так как все переменные в Java статически типизированы, то можно резонно заявить, что интерпретатор вроде Jython будет быстрее, чем интерпретатор CPython. С другой стороны виртуальная машина Java, реализованная на  Python, почти гарантированно будет медленнее. И не рассчитывайте, что Ruby, Perl и т.д. будут лучше. Они не были на это рассчитаны. Они были рассчитаны на "скриптинг" - то, чем называется программирование на динамических языках.

Каждая операция, выполняемая в виртуальной машине обязательно затрагивает реальное оборудование. Виртуальные машины содержат заранее настроенные подпрограммы, которых в общем достаточно, чтобы исполнять любую последовательность логических операций. Виртуальная машина может и не определять новых машинных инструкций, но точно выполняет свои внутренние подпрограммы и различные сложные цепочки подпрограмм. Виртуальная машина Java, также как и виртуальная машина Python и все остальные виртуальные машины общего назначения идентичны в том смысле, что вы можете запрограммировать их выполнять любую логическую последовательность, однако разные в том, какие задачи они берут на себя, а какие оставляют на совести программиста.

Мораль сей истории такова, что информация о базовых типах данных действительно помогает компилятору/виртуальной машине.

Наконец, чтобы окончательно всех запутать, представьте: программа на Python выполняется интерпретатором/виртуальной машиной на Python, которая выполняется на интерпретаторе/виртуальной машине Java, которая выполняется на LLVM в quemu, который выполняется на iphone.

---

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732383/3049150

Замечания:

* Однако вам всё же необходимо вручную заботиться о копировании сложных типов данных. К ним **не** относятся строки, числа (int), bool - они копируются без проблем, а вот всевозможные сложные структуры данных копируются по ссылке, для их полного копирования (например, вложенных словарей) необходимо использовать библиотеку deepcopy.

** Вообще можно добиться создания обычного типа int для Си, используя Cython. Но это лишь в CPython, насколько мне известно, а он не является частью инфраструктуры python-core

---

**Дополнение 2:**

В Python3 таки сделали возможность [объявить аргументы функций типизированными](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/). Как со всем этим теперь жить [можно почитать в документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). Однако встречается это крайне редко, потому что во Python2 это портироваться не будет, а из-за совместимости естественно используют это редко. Официальная дата смерти Python2 - 2020 год.

Официальная позиция разработчиков Python - это сделано для работы статических анализаторов программ с целью выявления ошибок. Но, как мне кажется, ещё и для того, чтобы сделать Python быстрее. Раньше все требования по входным аргументам прописывались в docstring, единого формата не было.

Comment: Но ведь, если при запуске программы получается байт-код, то это не совсем интерпретируемый язык, т.к. для запуска необходима компиляция, разве нет ?

Comment: @faoxis Да, но компилируются в байт-код только те модули, которые импортируются в процессе работы запускаемого скрипта. Сам модуль, который запускает пользователь в байт-код не компилируется. Также, есть интерактивный режим работы, в котором не происходит компиляция кода.

Comment: @faoxis дополнил ответ

Comment: @mkkik Какой "модуль который запускает пользователь" вы имеете в виду? Если тот, который содержит в себе \_\_main__, то он тоже компилируется. Вот интерактивный режим действительно ничего не компилирует, всё просто интерпретируется напрямую (под капотом то наверняка, просто не сохраняет)

Comment: @faoxis: стоит упомянуть, что многие вещи в этом ответе являются личным мнением FeroxTL и другие Питон-программисты могут иметь отличающиеся взгляды (интерпретировать факты по-другому) например, Cython это язык (надстройка над Питоном, чтобы с С более эффективно взаимодействовать), байт-код не является обязательной частью Питона, также как и Java Питон код может компилироваться в машинный код (c помощью JIT-компилятора во время исполнения) итд.

Comment: @jfs распишите поподробнее в виде ответа, я бы с удовольствием выслушал иную точку зрения. С Cython действительно практически не работал, а информации в рунете не так уж и много